# Can we get Queue Messages With perticular MessageGroupId in Amazon SQS fifo queue?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

my question is I have one fifo queue contains thousands of Messages I required to get only messages only with MessageGroupId how can it is possible.
means amazon provide any filter for its attributes.
because it get all messages not for particular id.
thanks it should be appreciate if help me.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't request a specific message or messages with specific attributes.  The messages are delivered in groups, in order.  Queues are, after all, queues... they are not designed for random access or querying... and a design assumption is that any consumer polling the queue is able to handle any message consumed from the queue.